# Dismissing GameCenter View in Swift

Tags: swift, game-center

After showing a Game Center view it doesn't dismiss after tapping done.  Here's my code to show it:

```
let gameCenterController = GKGameCenterViewController()

    self.presentViewController(gameCenterController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

There is some good Q&A on this over at Ray Wenderlich.  See the last method in the code below.  Source:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=18671

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {

    var skView: SKView!
    var scene: GameScene!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // View
        //------
        skView = self.view as SKView      
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        scene = GameScene.sceneWithSize(skView.bounds.size)
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        scene.view?.window?.rootViewController = self
        skView.presentScene(scene)

        authenticateLocalPlayer() 
    }


    override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        var touch:UITouch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
        var location:CGPoint = touch.locationInNode(scene)

        if (scene.gameCenterRect.contains(location) && GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated) {
            self.openGameCenter()
        }
    }


func openGameCenter() {
        var gameCenter = GKGameCenterViewController()
        gameCenter.gameCenterDelegate = self
        self.presentViewController(gameCenter, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func authenticateLocalPlayer(){
        var localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer()
        localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController, error) -> Void in
            if ((viewController) != nil) {
                self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }else{
                println("(GameCenter) Player authenticated: \(GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated)")                
            }

        }

    }


    func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController!) {
        gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

[...]   // standard methods

}
```